# LSTM output capped at a maximum

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I am using a LSTM built using to forecast a single-value (solar irradiance) by using weather data as my input.

When predicting my validation test, I get a weird results as it looks like all my predictions are capped at a maximum value:

[image]

Here is some details about what I did which might help flag any mistake I am doing:

- **Target**: I am forecasting a 20-minute horizon at 1-minute resolution
- **Data**: Test data is for a whole year at a 1-minute resolution (target and features)
- **Features**: I created 20 lagged features for each original feature (lag is a minute long each time)
- **Preprocessing**:

  - MinMaxScaler to bound values between 0 and 1
  - Reshape to fit LSTM
- **Model**: LSTM (Long-Short Term Memory), see details below:

```py
def lstm_model():
    # Define layers
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=30, 
                   kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), # add some L2 to discourage learning complex patterns by penalising loss function
                   return_sequences=False, # return single GHI value, not the sequence of values
                   activation='tanh',
                   recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                   use_bias=True,
                   input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=0.10))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    
    # Define optimiser
    optimiser = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, 
                  loss='mean_squared_error', 
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error', root_mean_squared_error])
    
    return model
```

- **Training**:

  - Early stopping with `patience=3`
  - Batch size `32`
  - Trained on 2014 data, validated on 2015 data
- **Predictions**: preds in the plot are computed using `y_pred = model.predict(X_test)` for now (will compute 20-minute horizons once I solve this issue).

Any ideas what could be causing this? I thought about potentially adding the target as a lag feature as well as it will have it in its history when making future predictions.

Thanks for the help!

Edit 1:

Added the train data to the same graph.

Comment: This is likely an effect of your training data. If you could plot your training in the same graph prior to your prediction and actuals, that could be beneficial.

Comment: Hi @JesseSealand, thanks for the comment! I've updated the graph with the train data in green (validation is still blue and predictions red), but the train data does not seem very different from the validation data.